# How to know the coordinates in a grid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinates

I have a raster (a catchment area) and a weather station with its coordinates (imported as .txt in ArcGIS) in UTM system. I want to know which row and column of my grid belongs to this station. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the coordinate values of the north, south, east, and west edges of the grid and the number of rows and columns, then you can calculate the row and column of a known x,y point (your weather station) using the following equations:

> row = Math.round((numberRows - 1) * (north - y) / (north - south))
>
> column = Math.round((numberColumns - 1) * (x - west) / (east - west))

And this, of course, assumes that the raster is not rotated in any way, i.e. that it follows the usual north-is-up convention.